# PyInstaller, relative imports, and entry points

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I’m trying to use PyInstaller to package a command-line tool for Linux systems. Following is the repo filesystem layout:

```
repo_dir/
    ReadMe.md
    setup.py
    meerkat/
        meerkat.py
        api.py
        config.py
        errors.py
        __init__.py
```

The main entry point is `meerkat/meerkat.py`, which looks like:

```
import click
import requests

from . import VERSION
from . import api
from . import config
from . import errors
from . import log

[... logic ...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli(obj={})
```

When I build the executable via:

```
cd repo_dir
pyinstaller -F -p $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages meerkat/meerkat.py
```

... and then run the resulting executable, I get this error:

```
File "meerkat/meerkat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import VERSION
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I understand the general cause of the problem, since the same error occurs when running `python meerkat/meerkat.py version` instead of `python -m meerkat.meerkat version`.

[PEX allows you to specify the entry point](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/buildingpex.html#pex-m) at build time via the `-m meerkat.meerkat:cli` argument, but I have no idea how to make PyInstaller do something similar. Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Why use `from . import ` and not use just `import`? I suspect that `pyinstaller` tries to find the . module and fails. You can also try to include your modules as [hidden imports](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search).

Comment: Removing `from . import VERSION` in favor of just `import VERSION` results in `ImportError: No module named VERSION`. It's not clear to me how to change the import calls, or add them as hidden imports, in such a way that resolves this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just noticed that VERSION is not a file in your meerkat folder. Where is this located? You can use `pyinstaller -F -p -hidden-import=VERSION $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages meerkat/meerkat.py`, but you have to make sure that VERSION.py is in your `PYTHONPATH`, which I suspect is the problem.